# How to integrate KPL (Kinesis Producer Library) to Kinesis firehose directly without going through Kinesis Data Stream

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-kinesis, amazon-kinesis-firehose

I developed java application using KPL to write data into kinesis data stream and it working fine, now I'm trying to integrate directly to firehose, So I configured firehose as (Direct PUT or other sources) and trying to integrated with KPL, but it's not working, is any way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

KPL is used to put data into a kinesis data stream, as stated [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/streams/latest/dev/developing-producers-with-kpl.html) - so it can't be used to put data into firehose directly.

However, you may want to look into [AWS SDK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/firehose/latest/dev/writing-with-sdk.html) and [Kinesis agent](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/firehose/latest/dev/writing-with-agents.html)